# Can't get the time picker to grey out the dates in the Past

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a JSP Page where i want the time picker to grey out the past days and only show the dates from today to furture . i have tried the endDate option but it is not working .

Heres my jsp page

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec"
 uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Categories</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<c:url value="/static/css/header.css" />'>
<!-- <script
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-datepicker.de.js" charset="UTF-8"></script> -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/a549aa8780dbda16f6cff545aeabc3d71073911e/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


 
<style type="text/css">


table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

th {
text-align:center;
}
#categorySelect {
 text-align: center;
}

#categorySelect {
 margin: auto;
 width: 30%;
}

#123 {
 margin: auto;
 width: 50%;
}
p {
 font:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <jsp:include page="../shared/header.jsp">
  <jsp:param value="editCategories" name="currentPage" />
 </jsp:include>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
   <h2>Select Category</h2>
   <div class="text-muted">
    <h4>Choose a Category to Edit, Update and Schedule Changes</h4>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group" id="categorySelect">
  <select class="form-control" id="categoryMenu">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
   <c:forEach items="${category}" var="catitem">
     <option>${catitem}</option>
   </c:forEach>
  </select>
 </div>
 <br></br>

 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="updateCategory" method=POST id="form1">
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
        <tr>
        <th style="width:15%" >Property</th>
        <th style="width:40%">Present Value</th>
        <th style="width:45%">Edited Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="id1">Id</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" name="id" placeholder="Enter Id" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Cat Key</strong></td>
<!--         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey1" name="catKey1" placeholder="Enter CatKey" disabled></td> -->
       <td><p class="text-danger" id="catKey1">Cat Key</p></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="catKey" name="catKey" placeholder="Enter CatKey" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
        <td><p class="text-danger" id="name1">Name</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Icon</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="icon1">Icon</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="icon" name="icon" placeholder="Enter Icon"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Icon White</strong></td>
        <td><p class="text-danger" id="iconWhite1">Icon White</p></td>
         <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="iconWhite" name="iconWhite" placeholder="Enter IconWhite"></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center"><strong>Color</strong></td>
         <td><p class="text-danger" id="color1">Color</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="Enter Color"></td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
  <p align="center"><strong>Success Messages Of Services Catering The Category</strong></p>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" id="tab_logic">
    <tbody>
                  <!--   <tr id='addr1'></tr> -->
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight" id="tab_logic">
    <tbody>
                  <tr>
              
                  <td> <div class="checkbox" style="text-align:center">
                  <label><input type="checkbox" value="schedule" id="schedule" name="schedule">Schedule</label>
                     </div>
                   </td></tr><tr>
                   <td align="center"><div class="form-group" style="width:30%">
                   <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' >
                     <input type='text' class="form-control" name="date" id="date"/>
                     <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                      </span>
                   </div>
               </div>
              </td>
                  </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 <!--  <div class="checkbox" style="text-align:center">
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="schedule" id="schedule">Schedule</label>
     </div>
      <div class="form-group"  style="text-align:center;width:30%">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="text-align:center">
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" style="text-align:center"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div> -->
   
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
     <tr>
     
     <td colspan="3" align="center">
  <div class="form-group">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" id="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var t;
  $(function() {
   
   jQuery.validator.addMethod("validHex", function(value, element) {
    //return str.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null;
    if ( value.match(/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i) !== null)
     return true 
    else
    return false;
    
   });
   
    $('#form1').validate({
     rules: {
              icon: {
                  required: true,
                  url:true
              },
         color : {
          required:true,
          validHex: true
         }
           },
           messages: {
            icon:{
               required: "Can't be empty."
            },
            color:{
             required: "Can't be empty.",
             validHex: " Enter valid hex color"
            }
            
           }
       });
   
    var date = new Date();
          var d = new Date();        
          d.setDate(date.getDate());
    $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
     defaultDate: new Date(),
     format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
        endDate: d,
    });
    
   $("#categoryMenu").change(function() {
    var category = $("#categoryMenu").val(); 
    loadData(category);
    loadPosm(t);
    var y = $("#id1").text();
    loadPosmData(y);

   });
 
  });
  
  
  function loadPosm(num) {       
   $('#tab_logic').html("<tr id=addr1></tr>");
   
   for (var i =1 ; i<=num ; i++)
    { 
    $('#addr'+i).html("<td align='center' style='width:15%' id='pos"+i+"'><strong>"+ (i+1) +"</strong></td><td style='width:40%'><p class='text-danger' id='posm"+i+"'>"+i+"</p></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' id='posmi"+i+"' name='posmi"+i+"' placeholder='Enter POSM'></td>");
          $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
 
      
    }
  }
  function loadPosmData(category_id) {
   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : {
     catId : category_id
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false ,
    url : "printPosmDetails",
    success : function(data) {
   
     for(var i=1 ;i <=data.length ;i++) { 
      $("#pos"+i.toString()).html("<strong>"+data[i-1].name+"</strong>");
      $("#posm"+i.toString()).html("<strong>"+data[i-1].message+"</strong>");
      $("#posmi"+i.toString()).val(data[i-1].message);
     }
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }

   });
   
  }
  function loadData(category) {
   $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : {
     categor : category
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    async : false ,
    url : "printCategoryDetails",
    success : function(data) {
     $("#id1").html("<strong>"+ data.id + "</strong>");
    //  $("#id").val(data.id); 
     $("#id").attr('disabled','disabled');
    // $("#catKey").val(data.catkey); 
     $("#catKey1").html("<strong>"+ data.catkey + "</strong>");
     $("#catKey").attr('disabled','disabled');
     $("#name").val(data.name);
     $("#name1").html("<strong>"+ data.name + "</strong>");
     $("#icon").val(data.icon);
     $("#icon1").html("<strong>"+ data.icon + "</strong>");
     $("#iconWhite1").html("<strong>"+ data.icon_white + "</strong>");
     $("#iconWhite").val(data.icon_white);
     $("#color1").html("<strong>"+ data.color+ "</strong>");
     $("#color").val(data.color);
     $('#123').html(data.posmNumber);
     t=data.posmNumber;
    
    },
    error : function() {
     alert("error");
    }

   });

  }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me as to why this is happening .

Answer (score 0):

Add `minDate: 0` in your datepicker initialisation code if you want to disable past dates.

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
             defaultDate: new Date(),
             format:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
             endDate: d,
             minDate: 0
         });
```

Comment: Try once with only `minDate: 0` option set, removing all other options.